# How to show the 404 message but also show the header and footer?

Tags: laravel

If the user access to a page that exist for example  the conference details page "https://project.test/conference/1/conference-test" it works fine.

If the user acces a page that dont exist for example "https://project.test/test" it appears the default message of the 404.blade.php. But do you know how to show the header and the footer of the site and the 404 message in the content?

I have a template file like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">

@include('partials.head')
@yield('styles')
</head>

<body>

@include('partials.header')

@yield('content')

@include('partials.footer')


@yield('scripts')

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Laravel handles error and uses the error code to return view.

ex: (Error 404 will return `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`)

> Laravel makes it easy to display custom error pages for various HTTP status codes. For example, if you wish to customize the error page for `404` HTTP status codes, create a `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`. This file will be served on all `404` errors generated by your application.

You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#http-exceptions)

To display header and footer in that view, you need to create the file and include the header and footer view just like what you did in other view.